# Reverse command for undoing sudo apt autoremove package-name

Tags: apt, package-management, reinstall

What is the reverse command for undoing `sudo apt autoremove`?
For example the reverse command for undoing `sudo apt install gedit` is `sudo apt remove gedit`

I want to know what is the reverse command for undoing `sudo apt autoremove` I want to know where these packages (which will be removed by the autoremove command) are located in the hard drive, in which folder I would find these packages. I have to reinstall all packages which were removed by the `sudo apt autoremove` command.

Example:

I have to remove a package, for example the dbus package. When I type `sudo apt autoremove dbus` it says:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  avahi-daemon avahi-utils dbus dbus-user-session ipp-usb libavahi-core7
  libgnome-bg-4-1 screen-resolution-extra xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
  xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

Packages `avahi-daemon avahi-utils dbus dbus-user-session ipp-usb libavahi-core7 libgnome-bg-4-1 screen-resolution-extra xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` were removed, then package `dbus` was removed. Then I reinstalled the `dbus` package, but how do I reinstall all of the packages that were automatically removed by uninstalling dbus if I do not have the .deb files that I would need to  manually reinstall `avahi-daemon avahi-utils dbus dbus-user-session ipp-usb libavahi-core7 libgnome-bg-4-1 screen-resolution-extra xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`?

Comment: There is no such command. You must go into the logs, see what packages were removed, and manually reinstall them. "It's hard to fit all those neutrons back in the shiny uranium sphere."

Comment: why would you want to do this?!

Comment: does theses packages available in my hard drive before running "apt autoremove" command?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - what is the actual issue that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Did something break when you did autoremove, and you want to fix it? In that case, what broke, and give some background

Comment: i had explained it in question. please have a look on question again. thank you

Comment: What you describe has nothing to do with the `autoremove` command, some packages (b.c.d) have been remove because you removed a dependency (a) of these packages. If you want to get help with the reinstallation of these packages you need to tell us the names of the packages, something like a,b,c,d is nothing we can work with. Please check your logs and add the package names to your question.

Comment: the package a name is "xorg-dbus" and b,c,d,e,f,g,h,.... many packages, all my desktop environment like "shotwall, rhydmbox,gedit...."

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log | less
```

Look for the first line that says `Commandline: apt autoremove`. Two lines below it will show a list of which packages were automatically removed by this command. Then reinstall all of the packages in the list using `sudo apt install package1 package2` which will install all of the packages that were automatically removed before together with their dependencies.

Example:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon avahi-utils dbus dbus-user-session ipp-usb libavahi-core7 libgnome-bg-4-1 screen-resolution-extra xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

This also works for commands of the form `apt remove`. Look for the first line that says `Commandline: apt remove` and continue as before as mentioned in the previous paragraph.